# Acumatica PXUIFieldAttribute SetError giving error

Tags: acumatica

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to verify the value entered into my `Support Split` table, why am I unable to grab my `ItemExtension`?

```cs
protected void atcProjectCostCenterTable_CostCenterSplit_FieldVerifying(PXCache cache, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e, PXFieldVerifying InvokeBaseHandler)
{
    if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
        InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
    var row = (atcProjectCostCenterTable)e.Row;

    if (row.ContractID > 0)
    {
        decimal? hun = 100;
        PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt item = row.GetExtension<PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt>();

        if (CostCenterSplit.Select().Count >= 1)
        {
            if (item.UsrCostCenterSum.Value != hun)
            {
                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<atcProjectCostCenterTable.costCenterSplit>(cache, row, "Support Percentages must equal 100%");
                //throw new PXSetPropertyException("Cost Center Percentages must equal 100%", PXErrorLevel.Warning);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is ContractExt really an extension of atcProjectCostCenterTable ? Please provide us with these classes definitions

Comment: Its a extension of Contract, public class ContractExt: PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CT.Contract>{

Comment: Assuming row is of atcProjectCostCenterTable type(which should be the case when we look at your code), a call like  row.GetExtension<PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt>(); will give you this error, because ContractExt isn't an extension of atcProjectCostCenterTable

Comment: Please refer to T300 http://acumaticaopenuniversity.com/pdf/T300_Acumatica_Cust_Platform.pdf DAC Extensions section (p. 185)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick, please replace

```
PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt item = row.GetExtension<PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt>();
```

with

```
PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt item = Base.Project.Current.GetExtension<PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt>();
```

or

```
PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt item = Base.Project.Cache.GetExtension<PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt>(Base.Project.Current);
```

Your current code can not work because ContractExt extends Contract DAC, not atcProjectCostCenterTable. Since PMProject is inherited from Contract, DAC extensions defined for the Contract DAC are also available for PMProject instances.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Contract con = Base.Project.Current;
  PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt item = con.GetExtension<PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt>();
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.